# IOS 15.6 - Xcode 14.3 - How to fix "Asset validation failed Missing required icon file"?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, appicon

i don't know in which part of the development i changed something, but as i'm new in swiftui and xcode, i started getting this error:

---

The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0. To support older versions of iOS, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog.
Asset validation failed
Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0. To support older operating systems, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog. Make sure the Info.plist file includes appropriate entries referencing the file. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface (ID: eb029444-b41e-4ce4-8f78-e534cdb14e29)
Asset validation failed
Missing App Icon. An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels in PNG format must be included in the Asset Catalog of apps built for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS. Without this icon, apps cannot be submitted for review. For details, see https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/. (ID: 7ef48b27-e353-4f22-a190-24975dc3a56a)

---

at least the 1024px should work, i don't know what i'm missing, my target deployment is 15.6.
[image]

i don't have anything set in Info.plist , that also could be the problem hehe, i found a lot of this but for older xcode versions like 8, 9, and i'm using 14.3.

I think it happened after i updated xcode last time, that also could be the reason, any help will be appreciated

I've tried changed all the styles of AppIcon, also tried to add some finds in Info.plist, and save png image as jpg and convert it back to guarantee that wouldn't be any transparent, so i'm strugling myslef with this.

Gemfile

gem "cocoapods", '~> 1.12'

---

updates:

changing to older appIcon style:

[image: AppIcon]
[image: AppIcon2]

gave me now only this error:

[!] Error uploading ipa file:
[Application Loader Error Output]: ERROR: [ContentDelivery.Uploader] Asset validation failed (90704) Missing App Icon. An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels in PNG format must be included in the Asset Catalog of apps built for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS. Without this icon, apps cannot be submitted for review. For details, see https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/. (ID: 486fb23c-5863-4f4d-a0a8-decc4091c176)
[Application Loader Error Output]: Error uploading '/var/folders/nh/3zc2rzws2qqf_rh8fv76d2mr0000gn/T/c3ea612c-65d1-4e64-848d-bd938e4cb19e.ipa'.
[Application Loader Error Output]: Asset validation failed Missing App Icon. An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels in PNG format must be included in the Asset Catalog of apps built for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS. Without this icon, apps cannot be submitted for review. For details, see https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/. (ID: 486fb23c-5863-4f4d-a0a8-decc4091c176) (90704)
[Application Loader Error Output]: The call to the altool completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.

I removed the alpha channel and i get the same error:

[image: Alpha_channel]

updates:

I opened an older branch to see if there was any difference, and seems something in xcode or ios that now it is showing some warnings:

[image: Warnings]

I'm almost sure there is something related to the new xcode version or something apple change in app icon, because the code is the same.

Comment: Delete the AppIcon file in Assets and then re-create it, you may be dealing with an older version. Also, there are different App Icons for watchOS so if you are supporting it you need to create a version for that os too.

Comment: Check under "General" > "App Icons and Launch Screen", name there should reference the asset catalog image; perhaps that setting got scrambled somehow.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for fast response, I already tried to delete and change it a lot of times =/, I'm supporting only iphone and ipad, and in General appicon is set and Launch screen there is nothing to select

Comment: faced the same problem. @DiegoPereira, any update on a solution?